# Как узнать сколько осталось до конца урока? Ссылаясь на текущее время

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно узнать через сколько закончится урок.

Например:

Сейчас время: 10:20;
Урок заканчивается: в 11:10

Как узнать, сколько осталось?

```
<p id="clock"></p>
```

---

```
  let date = new Date(),
         hours = (date.getHours() < 10) ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours(),
         minutes = (date.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes(),
         seconds = (date.getSeconds() < 10) ? '0' + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes;

let dat = hours + ':' + minutes
let time = '10:20'

alert(dat-time)
```

Comment: переведи всё время в миллисекунды.....когда разница будет ноль - значит закончилось всё

Comment: и как мне это сделать?

Comment: переведи всё время в миллисекунды. вычти.